# Virtual DOM makes apps faster or slower?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, svelte, virtual-dom

I just read Svelte JS documentation which mention that the one of three plus point is no Virtual DOM in this framework that makes our apps faster and lighter. But I found some references that said, Virtual DOM is a way to fasten the apps and high performability (e.g React JS or Vue JS). So which one has the right theory?? thanks

Comment: It makes app faster, and increase its performance

Comment: The assumption is that the JavaScript code used to manage the Virtual DOM is faster than the browser code used to manage the actual DOM. This was certainly true when React first came out, but this will probably not be true forever.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual DOM changes are being calculated additionally to DOM calculations, since the change has to be rendered in the besaid DOM. Frameworks or Libs using Virtual DOM have an efficient approach to deal with changes so they can be applied in a performant way to the DOM. When it was introduced ~2013 there were plenty of frameworks that did worse. So there was definitely room for performance improvements with a different programming model.

Svelte, as a relatively new framework (2016) argues to deliver DOM changes [efficiently without the additional virtual DOM calculations (more details in their article)](https://svelte.dev/blog/virtual-dom-is-pure-overhead). It provides a similar programming model without relying on it.